# Is there a timeout event in cucumber-js

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumberjs

I am using cucumber-js to run tests with selenium-webdriver.
I want to add a screenshot capture of the browser when any step times out.
I am using global timeout for all the steps as:

```
this.setDefaultTimeout(3 * 60 * 1000);
```

in my hooks file.

How do I register to the global timeout event (if such even exists)?

Comment: Is it only on timeout that you want the screenshot to be taken, or would it be better for a screenshot to be taken on any error?

Comment: I prefer on timeout because most of the time the failures are because "wait for element" calls are timing out. I want to take a screenshot of those particular cases so that I can tell why the element never appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selenium Webdriver js do provide function to get screenshot, you just need to use it in `After`, which is similar to `@AfterClass` tag in `TestNG`

The `After` scenario will execute after every scenario in Feature and check the result of the Scenario, it it is FAILED it will take the screenshot.
The reason for failure can be anything, like a bug, or DEFAULT_TIMEOUT

You need to add this in your world.js

```
this.After(function (scenario) {

    if (scenario.isFailed()) {

        // take a screenshot
        // driver.takeScreenshot() is defined in webDriver.js
        return driver.takeScreenshot()
           .then(function (screenShot) {
               scenario.attach(new Buffer(screenShot, 'base64'), 'image/png'); 
               return driver.close()
                 .then(function () {
                    return driver.quit();
                 });
            });
    }
    else {
        return driver.close()
          .then(function () {
              return driver.quit();
          });
    }
});
```